# def python function would not return

Tags: python, json, function

So I want to make inventory from the JSON file and Why this code won't return anything?

```py
import os
import json

def get_data():
    with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/items.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

def save_data(data):
    with open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/items.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

def modify_item(name,category,mode):
    data = get_data()
    temp = data[str(category)]
    y = {str(name): 1}
    if mode == "+":
        for index in range(len(temp)):
            if data[str(category)][int(index)][str(name)] == str(name):
                data[str(category)][int(index)][str(name)] += 1
        return data
    elif mode == "-":
        data[str(category)][int(index)][str(name)] -= 1
        return data
    elif mode == "a":
        temp.append(y)
        return data

save_data(modify_item(name="Potato fries", category="Foods", mode="+"))
```

The json file

```json
{
    "Foods": [
        {
            "Potato fries": 1
        }
    ],
    "Misc": [
        {
            "Disc": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

It won't change the **"Potato fries"** key. The console just did not show the errors, Someone explain why?

Comment: The code for `+` and `-` modes are different. Why is that? In the `+` mode you are comparing `data[str(category)][int(index)][str(name)] == str(name)` where the left hand side will return the number of potato fries. You could do it just like the `-` mode `data[str(category)][int(index)][str(name)] += 1` without any loops etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "+" mode, your condition is never fulfilled, because you are comparing the name (string) to the value of the field name in your dictionary (in this case an int).

Surely not the best/cleanest way to do it but it works if you just replace your if with a try and except statement:

```
try:
    data[str(category)][int(index)][str(name)] += 1
except:
   print("Name given is not in the available categories.")
   break
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: Linking to w3schools always gets the "ugh" reaction from me. Do you have a specific reason to not simply link to the Python documentation?

Comment: That would have been better to not link anything I agree.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#
(Didn't think that much about it, just took a search-result that seemed clear and correct)